# How to make a average in a piechart?

Tags: dc.js, crossfilter

Hello I would like to print a piechart with this dataset:

```
data1 data1
1      2    
2      3 
3      4
```

So i would like to make a average each data: data 1 and data2

So i need to sumup the data up count the rows and calculate the avg.
But how can i implement this? The the Average can be in the hover by getting over the chart with a mouse.
How is the definition of the dimensions and groups to print it in a chart?

Step 1 i like to declare it in this chart

```
Chart1
          .width(250)
          .height(250)
          .slicesCap(4)
          .innerRadius(0)
          .dimension(??)

          .title(function(d){return "The Average is " + d.value +";})
          .colors(d3.scaleOrdinal(["#ff2222","#4855ff"]))
          .label(function (d:any) {
            if (Chart1.hasFilter() && !Chart1.hasFilter(d.key)) {
              return d.key + ' (0%)';
            }
            var label = d.key;
            if (all.value()) {
              label += ' (' + Math.floor(d.value / all.value() * 100) + '%)';
            }
            return label ;
          })
          .group(??);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it. If you took the average of the values, then you would only have one value and a pie chart with only one value isn't very informative. The average across a crossfilter group is just `d3.sum(group.all(), kv => kv.value)/group.all().length` but that's clearly not what you're asking.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to display the average separately from the chart, then clearly you don't need to change the dimension or group of the chart, since the chart is fine.